# Matching people based on names, DoB, address, etc

Tags: algorithm, search, compare

I have two databases that are differently formatted. Each database contains person data such as name, date of birth and address. They are both fairly large, one is ~50,000 entries the other ~1.5 million.

My problem is to compare the entries and find possible matches. Ideally generating some sort of percentage representing how close the data matches. I have considered solutions involving generating multiple indexes or searching based on Levenshtein distance but these both seem sub-optimal. Indexes could easily miss close matches and Levenshtein distance seems too expensive for this amount of data.

Comment: There are many strategies for doing this, and a lot of companies that offer this kind of service. Depending on the data quality, the problem ranges from very easy to really difficult. Sometimes, when the data is bad (foe example mistyped names) and the results must be 100% accurate, a final "manual" pass is included. I guess we may help more if you specify some conditions on your data and on your expected results

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'll be needing a final manual pass as well. Most likely I'll be generating a report that two or three people will have to work their way through. 

Unfortunately I don't know much about the data myself yet. The ~1.5 million entries dataset I'm familiar with because that's our data but the other final doesn't have a final spec yet and I haven't even received a hints how it will be structured or what specifically it will contain. ATM I'm just trying to plan out the procedure.

Comment: Assuming mistyped or alternate (ie. middle initial) names are entirely possible and 100% accurate matches is the (likely impossible) goal. What would be your first thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: @kutusof Ok. Let me articulate an answer. The issue is too broad, and I don't want to write a book :) Let's see if I can put a few ideas together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try to put a few ideas together. The general situation is too broad, and these will be just guidelines/tips/whatever.

Usually what you'll want is not a true/false match relationship, but a scoring for each candidate match. That is because you never can't be completely sure if candidate is really a match.

The score is a relation one to many. You should be prepared to rank each record of your small DB against several records of the master DB.

Each kind of match should have assigned a weight and a score, to be added up for the general score of that pair.

You should try to compare fragments as small as possible in order to detect partial matches. Instead of comparing [address], try to compare [city] [state] [street] [number] [apt].

Some fields require special treatment, but this issue is too broad for this answer. Just a few tips. Middle initial in names and prefixes could add some score, but should be kept at a minimum (as they are many times skipped). Phone numbers may have variable prefixes and suffixes, so sometimes a substring matching is needed. Depending on the data quality, names and surnames must be converted to soundex or similar. Streets names are usually normalized, but they may lack prefixes or suffixes.

Be prepared for long runtimes if you need a high quality output.

A porcentual threshold is usually set, so that if after processing a partially a pair, and obtaining a score of less than x out of a max of y, the pair is discarded.

If you KNOW that some field MUST match in order to consider a pair as a candidate, that usually speeds the whole thing a lot.

The data structures for comparing are critical, but I don't feel my particular experience will serve well you, as I always did this kind of thing in a mainframe: very high speed disks, a lot of memory, and massive parallelisms. I could think what is relevant for the general situation, if you feel some help about it may be useful.

HTH!

PS: Almost a joke: In a big project I managed quite a few years ago we had the mother maiden surname in both databases, and we assigned a heavy score to the fact that = both surnames matched (the individual's and his mother's). Morale: All Smith->Smith are the same person :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Full text search feature maybe, if your DBMS supports it? Full text search builds its indices, and can find similar word.

Would that work for you?

Comment: The data isn't currently in an actual database they're just blocks of data dumped from an old non-relational database. Loading them into a modern database using a LILKE function or something similar would be an option but it would be much simpler if I could implement something on my own which only worked with two flat files.